# How to use lottie-web to get animated icons in angular11?

Tags: icons, lottie, angular11

I works an angular project.Ii need animated icons into my project. so i am going to use lottie-web. I have installed lottie-web. I followed this guide https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-web. But icon does not display.
Can anyone help me please..